# Presenting hierarchical data in Pattern lab

Tags: json, patternlab.io

My team is experimenting with [Pattern Lab](https://patternlab.io/). We have run into a problem when trying to combine "organisms" to form an instantiated template. The issue is that while we have hierarchical JSON data, we cannot target the individual organisms with different data, since we can't see a way to pass parameters about what JSON to use to the organisms. As the screen shot below shows, we are able to populate the organism headlines using `Pattern Parameters`, but the content inside each organism stays identical.

Pattern Lab's [documentation](https://patternlab.io/docs/using-pattern-parameters/) states that *"Pattern parameters do not currently support (…) modifying/replacing variables in patterns included **within** the targeted pattern"*.

Are there any other ways of populating said organisms? If not, how is it possible to use Pattern Lab's recommended "atomic" structure while visualizing a fully populated template?

[image]